# How to achieve consistent transactions in ORMs?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, transactions, consistency, acid

My question is of a conceptual nature.

Let's assume we use an ORM (like Entity Framework, Hibernate, ...) and model our domain objects in those ORMs. Since the ORM will abstract away most SQL / do transactions for us, how can we make sure our transactions will be consistent?

Example:
We have an online shop that sells books. If we sell a book, we would basically use something similar to this:

```
var book = books.Single(b => b.Id == 42);
book.Quantity -= 1;
books.SaveChanges();
```

But if I understood ORMs correctly, they will only wrap the change of book in an UPDATE query. Meaning you could get basic concurrency issues like this:
[concurrency issue with orms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fr7y.png)

If you would use SQL, you would just wrap the .Quantity -= 1 in a transaction and be safe.

How would you usually deal with this in a proper way in ORMs, or is this handled somehow automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a select for update before you change the quantity. This will lock the record.

It depends on the ORM you are using. With Hibernate you can set the LockModeType when doing the query.

In Hibernate this would be LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Read more about locking in the Hibernate documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking

Comment: Well I shouldn't have to use a select for update, if the update query is just the delta to the last. Since one update statement is atomic, there cannot be a lost update? Or do you mean there is no possibility to do this without locking in "usual" ORMs?

Comment: The update statement is atomic but that means that you must issue the update statement and not select the data with orm and the do the change and persist the data with orm. there will be time between select and update

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework uses [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) for this.  And most RDBMS systems won't prevent this update anomaly using a transaction.

```
UPDATE T SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE ID = :ID
```

This single statement will run atomically, and while using a single statement will prevent lost updates, it won't guarantee that Quantity doesn't get reduced below zero.

A pessimistic lock requires not just a transaction, but either locking hints or an elevated transaction isolation level.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a higher transaction isolation level won't prevent these anomalies, since the transactions don't interfere.
But I still don't get how I would do this in EF. Using the quantity as a concurrency token would create many DbUpdateConcurrencyExceptions, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: Transactions and higher isolation level will prevent anomalies, but may do so by generating exceptions or deadlocks.  And Optimistic concurrency always works by creating Exceptions to prevent lost updates.